# Book for non parametric statistics

Tags: nonparametric, references, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

What would be a good book for non-parametric statistics. Not just the introduction but advanced level. Also I am looking at something I can use for learn and not for reference.

In particular I am looking for a book that can contain basics behind non-parametric methods, non-parametric inference, methods to evaluate non parametrics, e.g., KS test, $t$ test, etc. , bootstrapping ....

Comment: Nonparametric statistics is a large field, but I'd guess *All of Nonparametric Statistics* by Larry Wassermann should be a reasonable starting point. I don't know if I would call it "advanced level" but he sketches the proofs of many of the results in the book. Topics include the bootstrap, smoothing techniques, density estimation, regression, and lots of other things. No nonparametric Bayes, however.

Comment: I have checked that one out but its more like a reference book than learning material. No?

Comment: I disagree, it should be fine for learning from. If I'm remembering correctly, he wrote it for people who hadn't seen nonparametric methods before, such computer science students he teaches.

Comment: Are you looking for 'distribution free' stuff, or nonparametrics in the sense of "infinite parametric", whether it applies to distributions, relationships between variables or whatever else? For example, I can assume a linear relationship for $(Y|X=x)$ without a distributional assumption, or I can *assume* that $Y$ is normal and not assume the relationship with $X$ is anything but 'smooth'... both can be referred to as 'nonparametric', even though each is parametric in one aspect (if potentially infinite-parametric in another).

Comment: I am looking for distribution free stuff .

Comment: I think that expanding this answer to give a little more detail would make it more likely to attract good responses. For example, terms like "advanced" are nebulous and can be misinterpreted. :)

Comment: +1 on the Wassermann book. *Nonparametric Statistics with Applications to Science and Engineering* by  Kvam and Vidakovic is also quite hoppy. Not really mathematical but I enjoyed its "problem-oriented" approach.

Comment: t tests don't qualify as non-parametric -- except in a special sense that they are often surprisingly robust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think of the Encyclopaedia Britannica of nonparametric statistics as being:

- Hollander, M, & Wolfe, D (1999). [Nonparametric Statistical Methods, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471190454). Wiley.

I'm not sure if I would characterize this as introductory or advanced.  Many of the sections are a bit terse, in my opinion, and are written with a good deal of mathematical notation.  This will be intimidating / off-putting for people who have some math anxiety. On the other hand, it's not really *deriving* theorems, it's just using mathematical notation to express the ideas.  There are some problems included at the end of each section; you could definitely use the book to learn nonparametric statistics.

For a treatment that is much more introductory:

- Higgins, J. (2003). [Introduction to Modern Nonparametric Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534387756). Duxbury.

will be much less intimidating, I think.  I have skimmed some portions of it, and it seems to be a gentle introduction for people who don't have a strong statistical background.  It is very clear, but does not have anything like the depth or coverage of Hollander & Wolfe.

Comment: I don't have a recommendation for a book that focuses primarily on the mathematical theory behind nonparametric statistics.

Comment: In november 2013 the [third edition](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470387378.html) of Hollander & Wolfe appeared and a corresponding GNU R package [NSM3](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NSM3/index.html) is available.

Comment: I find it confusing how you refer to the Encyclopaedia Britannica, when in fact the book does not come from the Encyclopaedia Britannica. In fact, the Encyclopaedia Britannica [has an entry on nonparametric statistics](https://academic.eb.com/levels/collegiate/article/statistics/108592#60722.toc).

Comment: I think @gung-ReinstateMonica was just writing figuratively and alluding to a source that is a reference, large and definitive.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [*All of Nonparametric Statistics*, by Larry Wasserman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387251456). The title says it all ;)
The reviews for the book are outstanding. I cannot tell for myself, since I have not read it yet. But it seems to have all the theoretical background you are looking for, plus it has also a focus on applications, i.e. it well help you to put those techniques into use quickly.

Comment: Provide the name of book in the answer, not only the link, please! :)

Comment: Despite the title, this isn't a book that focuses on Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney, Kruskal-Wallis and that bundle of nonparametric significance tests, which many readers of this thread may be looking for. As always, you can check out a book's aims and contents from material or Amazon or the publisher's website.

Answer (score 2):

Nonparametric statistics is to a good extent a disjoint collection of tests and estimators.  Especially for tests, I suggest instead using [semiparametric regression models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) as a unifying framework.  Commonly used tests such as the Wilcoxon and Kruskal-Wallis tests may be obtained as special cases of the proportional odds semiparametric ordinal logistic regression model.  A better rank-based approach than the Wilcoxon signed-rank statistic may be [obtained likewise](https://fharrell.com/post/pair).  The regression framework easily extends to allow covariate adjustment and longitudinal data.

I’ve taken this approach in my introductory e-book [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).

Answer (score 1):

The best nonparametric statistics book is

- Hollander, M.; Wolfe, D.A.; Chicken, E. *Nonparametric statistical methods*. Hoboken: Wiley, 2014. 848 p.

Lehmann’s book is a classic, but it doesn’t cover all the methods in Hollander et al. It has a balanced mix of teaching, practical examples, useful exact tables, and nifty proof sketches in the appendix.

- Lehmann, E.L. *Nonparametrics: statistical methods based on ranks*. New York: Springer, 2006. 480 p.

The main focus of Hettmansperger’s book is rank-based methods, leaning towards a more rigorous style. The books by Randles & Wolfe and Gibbons & Chakraborti have a somewhat similar approach:

- Gibbons, J.D.; Chakraborti, S. *Nonparametric statistical inference*. Boca Raton: CRC Press, 2021. 694 p.
- Hettmansperger, T.P. *Statistical inference based on ranks*. New York: Wiley, 1984. 380 p.
- Randles, R.H.; Wolfe, D.A. *Introduction to the theory of nonparametric statistics*. New York: Wiley, 1979. 450 p.

Conover and Siegel & Castellan wrote great books with a more practical, applied treatment. They also describe a few techniques that aren’t in the books I mentioned above.

- Conover, W.J. *Practical nonparametric statistics*. New York: Wiley, 1999. 608 p.
- Siegel, S.; Castellan Jr., N.J. *Nonparametric statistics for the behavioral sciences*. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1988. 399 p.